# How to set SwifMailer plugins when using the Laravel mail class?

Tags: email, laravel, swiftmailer

Laravel does not return any useful information to show the reason that email fails. The SwifMailer [Logger plugins](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/plugins.html#logger-plugin) helps with debugging during the process of sending. What is the correct way to set this plugin (and other swifmailer plugins) when emails are sent through Laravel's Mail class?

Comment: The same question is over here, and I just answered it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53783301/470749

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
Mail::getSwiftMailer()->registerPlugin();
```

You can place this code into some service provider for example to be executed on application startup. Or you can override `Illuminate\Mail\Mailer` entirely if you want.