# How to get SMTP sesion error with SwiftMailer in Laravel

Tags: laravel, email, smtp, swiftmailer

I try to send email to fake address. And I can't catch error if this email address is not available and email can not be delivered.
In SMTP-server logs I see:

```
Fri 2020-12-11 12:08:58.582: 03: --> 250-STARTTLS
Fri 2020-12-11 12:08:58.582: 03: --> 250 SIZE
Fri 2020-12-11 12:08:58.582: 02: <-- MAIL FROM:<my_email@mydomain.com>
Fri 2020-12-11 12:08:58.583: 03: --> 250 2.1.0 Sender OK
Fri 2020-12-11 12:08:58.583: 02: <-- RCPT TO:<somefakeaddress@mydomain.com>
Fri 2020-12-11 12:08:58.584: 03: --> 550 5.1.1 Recipient unknown <mi@f
Fri 2020-12-11 12:08:58.585: 02: <-- RSET
Fri 2020-12-11 12:08:58.585: 03: --> 250 2.0.0 RSET? Well, OK
Fri 2020-12-11 12:08:58.586: 02: <-- QUIT
Fri 2020-12-11 12:08:58.586: 03: --> 221 2.0.0 See ya in cyberspace
Fri 2020-12-11 12:08:58.586: 04: SMTP session terminated (Bytes in/out
```

But in my Laravel app I can't catch this error even if I use Event Listeners https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail#events

Of course, the code

```
Mail::to('somefakeaddress@mydomain.com')->send(new Mailable($mail_data));
```

returns nothing.

**Is there any idea how to catch the error of the SMTP session in Laravel?**

Comment: do you have any errors in laravel logs

Comment: no errors in Laravel log

Comment: try to use Swift_TransportException

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution:

Add SwiftMailer plugin to mailer

```
$mailer = Mail::getSwiftMailer();

$logger = new \Swift_Plugins_Loggers_ArrayLogger();

$mailer->registerPlugin(new \Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin($logger));
```

Then we can send mail as usual:

```
Mail::to(...)->send(new Mailable($data_for_mailable_class));
```

And after that we can search for any error messages in $logger array.

For test I use `dump($logger);`

This helped me find a solution:
[How to set SwifMailer plugins when using the Laravel mail class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33863328/how-to-set-swifmailer-plugins-when-using-the-laravel-mail-class)

Comment: nice though you can also use try catch & catch all the Swift_TransportException

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that too